# API GET request returns an empty response but postman does not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api

I am trying to make an API call to a remote server, Initially, I got this error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I temporarily solve this error by attaching the `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com` link before the link, or sometimes using the Moesif Cors-Any-where Chrome extension. The fetch now returns `200 ok status` but the response is empty.

```
body: ReadableStream
locked: true
__proto__: ReadableStream
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"

response: {}
data: undefined
```

However, if I run the same query on postman, it returns the expected response JSON object. How do I fix this?

```
 const searchFlightData = (to, from, depDate, adults) => {
        fetch(`http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/prices/direct?origin=${from}&destination=${to}&depart_date=2017-11&return_date=2017-12&token=${tp_token}`)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    console.log(response)
                    return response
                }
                else
                    console.log(`Looks like something went wrong. Status: ${response.status}`)
            })
            .then(response => {
                response.json()
                console.log("response: " + JSON.stringify(response))
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log("data: " + data)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`response.json()` returns a promise, you have to wait for resolving this. you also have to return something if you want the next `then` in the chain to receive something.

something like this should work:

```
 const searchFlightData = (to, from, depDate, adults) => {
        fetch(`http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/prices/direct?origin=${from}&destination=${to}&depart_date=2017-11&return_date=2017-12&token=${tp_token}`)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response
                } else {
                    throw `Looks like something went wrong. Status: ${response.status}`;
                }
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log("data: " + data)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
}
```

or with your console.log:

```
return response.json().then((data) => console.log(data));
```

Comment: I believe that was what I did. Could the problem be the ```Access-Control-Allow-Origin``` issue?

Comment: do you see the response in the developer tools?

Comment: No, it's an empty array. But the exact same request on postman returns a full response

Comment: if you get an array as response i think the problem is not the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. the problem may be `cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com` or your backend.

do you use cookies to check for login? `cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com` is stripping all cookies. so you will not be logged in if you send your request via this tool.

Comment: TheWuif I appreciate your help. I'm getting an empty object as a response, and instead of ```cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com``` I'm using a google chrome extension Moesif Origin and CORS changer, still the same result, even though postman returns result

Comment: and you can exclude any problem with the backend? something the backend is doing different if you do a postman call vs ajax calls? something with headers or anything like that?

Answer (score 1):

Add A Header For accept all  as follow in the front-end request

[image: Axios request header]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to request data from a server it has to be on the same domain, or the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header` has to be set.
I wont rely on a service like `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com`

For development you can use a `proxy server` to bypass this limitation. (many frameworks already have a solution for this, i don't know which one you use)

Comment: The problem is I'm not using a server yet. My project is only at the front end for now, that's why I'm using proxy. The chrome extension also works. Could that be the reason for my empty response?

Comment: posted a new answer which should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but I've got exact same problem last night. The issue was the SSL connection, which is enforced by Chrome and is not enforced by Postman. So just make sure your API can handle `https` protocol.